# Can't import CV2 on Virtual Environment on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, virtual-environment

I'm having a problem with importing cv2 on a virtual environment (windows 10). However, when I use Python interpreter and write `import cv2`, I can import it. It's when I try to run the script from the command prompt, I get an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I've tried some solutions on the previous Stack overflow posts but none of them worked for me. I tried with both Python 3.7 and Python 3.8 with a separate virtual environment.

I checked that cv2 folder is in the site-packages folder.

The solutions I've tried are:

1. Change the name of `cv2.py` to `cv.py` inside the cv2 folder.
2. Install cv2 through `pip install opencv-contrib-python` then `pip install opencv-python`
3. Install `opencv_python‑4.5.5‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl`

Any suggestion?

Comment: could you try installing with `pip3 install opencv-python3` ?

Comment: It's giving me an error: 
"ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python3"

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MacOS, but maybe it'll help. Working in the CLI try "pip list" in the virtual environment. Look to see if opencv-python is listed. It wasn't for me, so I typed "pip install opencv-python" in the CLI. Then try "pip list" to check if opencv is listed. It was, so then I was able to get "install cv2" to work.